# Calculate contentOffset from right side of screen in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uikit

By default, `scrollView.contentOffset = 0` means left edge (side) of `scrollView` (UIScrollView).

Is there anyway to change this behavior? Something like making Right-to-Left UIScrollView, that it's `contentOffset = 0` means right edge (side) of scrollView.

Comment: did you try change `Semantic` to **Force Right-to-Left**  in Attributes inspector ?

Comment: change values to negative it will move right to left.

Comment: Are you aiming to make a horizontal scroll view?

Comment: @arash Yes, I did. changing `Semantic` to `.forceRightToLeft` did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
let rightOffset = scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.contentOffset.x
```

that way you can

*Calculate contentOffset from right side of screen in UIScrollView*